# nagios core not honouring scheduled downtime parent child

Tags: parent-child, nagios, downtime

We have a nagios core 4.4.10. We do use the [parent child relations](https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/parent-child-host-relationships-904.html). So in Windows environment do have hyper-v hosts. The hosts running multiple VMs which are also monitored.

We do use (or trying) scheduled downtime. For  that I created a time period, with an exclude, so for example at every Monday from 4 am to 6 am, some host are scheduled for downtime.

I only added the physical hyper-v hosts to this time period. My problem is that if the hyper-v host is gets back online and the VMs are still booting or in down state, we are getting notifications. How can I avoid this?
Is this an expected behaviour?
I know I can add all the VMs to the scheduled downtime settings, but is much more work.

I tried manually to set up a new downtime window, and checked the behaviour. I do not know if I am missing some information, or is this how nagios should work.

Thanks
Peter

Comment: verify that you are putting the child objects in downtime as well, there is a checkbox for that when sending the downtime and a yellow clock icon will show in the host list.